cargar la edicion de una lista desplegable en cascada
Amigos como estan, tengo el siguiente codigo en javascript que me carga las listas desplegables en cascada de Departamento, Provincia y Distrito. Al inicio se quedan desabilitas las opciones de provincia y distrito hasta que se seleccione un departamento, una vez seleccionado se habilita la provincia y asi hasta el distrito.
En el metodo crear funciona perfectamente al momento de crear los datos del usuario, cargan las listas y se guarda la informacion, pero al momento de la edicion, no se estan cargando los datos correspondientes, se quedan en blanco para que de nuevo se vuelva a seleccionar los valores, espero me puedan ayudar


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_departamento').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#select_provincia').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
    CargarDepartamento();

    $('#select_departamento').change(function () {
        var departamentoId = $(this).val();
        if (departamentoId > 0) {
            CargarProvincia(departamentoId);
        }
        else {
            alert("Seleccione Departamento");
            $('#select_provincia').empty();
            $('#select_distrito').empty();
            $('#select_provincia').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#select_provincia').append('<option>--Select Provincia--</option>');
            $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Select Distrito--</option>');
        }
    });

    $('#select_provincia').change(function () {
        var provinciaId = $(this).val();
        if (provinciaId > 0) {
            CargarDistrito(provinciaId);
        }
        else {
            alert("Seleccione Provincia");
            $('#select_distrito').empty();
            $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Select Distrito--</option>');
        }
    });
});

function CargarDepartamento() {
    $('#select_departamento').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Propietarios/GetDepartamento',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#select_departamento').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#select_departamento').append('<option>--Select Departamento--</option>');
                $('#select_provincia').append('<option>--Select Provincia--</option>');
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Select Distrito--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#select_departamento').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.departamento + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#select_departamento').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_provincia').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_departamento').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
                $('#select_provincia').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function CargarProvincia(departamentoId) {
    $('#select_provincia').empty();
    $('#select_distrito').empty();
    $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Propietarios/GetProvincia?Id=' + departamentoId,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#select_provincia').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#select_provincia').append('<option>--Select Provincia--</option>');
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Select Distrito--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#select_provincia').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.provincia + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#select_provincia').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_provincia').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function CargarDistrito(provinciaId) {
    $('#select_distrito').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Propietarios/GetDistrito?Id=' + provinciaId,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Select Distrito--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#select_distrito').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.distrito + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#select_distrito').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#select_distrito').append('<option>--Desabilitado--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Departamento</label>
    <select asp-for="UbigeoId" class="form-select" id="select_departamento" required></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="UbigeoId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Provincia</label>
    <select asp-for="UbigeoProvId" class="form-select" id="select_provincia" required></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="UbigeoProvId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Distrito</label>
    <select asp-for="UbigeoDistId" class="form-select" id="select_distrito" required></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="UbigeoDistId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>




Saludos
Te sugiero lo siguiente:
1.- Modificar
// Variables globales; inicializadas en null (el que corresponda indica no seleccionado)
var idDepto = null;
var idPro = null;
var idDis = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
   // Todo lo anterior

   // A continuación lo que se indica en el paso 2 (abajo)
   CargarDepartamento(); // Pasar ésta línea al final
}

2.- Para cada elemento en cascada
(Apoyándote de variables auxiliares)
En caso de nuevo:

Establecer el valor al que corresponda que aun no ha sido seleccionado.

En caso de edición:

Establecer el valor al que corresponda al dato seleccionado.

3.- Validar el dato y estado del select
En cada procedimiento CargarDepartamento, CargarProvincia y CargarDistrito donde poblas el select con los option aplicar en su append:
// Usar la variable global idDepto, idPro o idDis según el elemento poblando
// Por ejemplo con idDepto
$.each(response, function (i, data) {
   $('#select_departamento').append('<option value=' + data.id + ' ' + (data.id == idDepto ? 'selected' : '' )+ ' >' + data.provincia + '</option>');
});
idDepto = null; // Indicamos no seleccionado para cada elemento
// Esperamos un momento antes de pasar al siguiente elemento y variable global
setTimeout(function () {
   $('#select_provincia').val(idPro)
   $('#select_provincia').change()
}, 200);


Cuidado con el tipo de datos que cada data.id es respecto al que tengas en la variable global.

De la forma que expongo es como lo he controlado; el comportamiento de primero a cada select asignar el valor actual (sea de nuevo o edición) no siempre ha dado buenos resultado al repoblar el componente.
Desde luego, para cuando el usuario vuelve a interactuar moviendo opciones, como su variable global esta a null ya no se establece como valor seleccionado ninguno.
